# android: making ON/OFF button

Tags: android

I have a button on the main_menu XML file, this button will filter some of the things in an RecyclerView.

When I click the button it Filters all the values I want, and if I click it a Second time it goes back to being unfiltered, the Code I need is the ON/OFF Function, it doesn't have to be a function, not the Filter code.

Thanks for all kinds of Feedback my great souls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use switch button for this.Its just a sample code from a part of my app

`

```
aSwitch= findViewById(R.id.swich);
        boolean value = false;
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ischecked",0);
        value = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ischecked",value);
        aSwitch.setChecked(value);
        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (aSwitch.isChecked()){
                    aSwitch.setText("Enabled");
//YOUR TARGET CODE HERE
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("ischecked",true).apply();

                    setSharedPreferences(false);

                }
                else {
                    aSwitch.setText("Disabled");
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("ischecked",false).apply();
                    setSharedPreferences(true);
//YOUR CODE HERE
                }
            }
        });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Switch in Android is simply a CompoundButton,
you can add switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener() to give filtered or unfiltered list to your Recyclerview as follows

```
  switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b) {
            //filtered list
            } else {
            //unfiltered list
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

In the Design View of main.activity_xml file, in pallete; there is an option of a switch.  That can be used as the yes/no button

If u want the source code than;

```
$<switch
```

$android:id="@+id/simple_YesNoswitch"

$android:layout_width="wrap_content"

$android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: ignore the dollar sign in each line of code. I m new here so i don't exactly know how to annotate a piece of code is Stack Overflow